# GraphQL returning duplicates (that don't exist) on the front end but not the back

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

When using graphql sandbox to test data I query for from a MongoDB, multiple unique datapoints relevant to my query is returned, BUT when I use the same query on the front end I am given an array of one datapoint multiple times (equal to number put inside .limit())

Query works fine on Mongo and apollo sandbox but not when called from the front end.

This is the relevant resolver:

```
> players: async (parent, { id }) => {
> return Player.find({ id: id }).sort({ game_id: -1 }).limit(3);
>     },
>
```

These are the relevant typeDefs

```
> type Player {
> _id: ID
> game_id: Int
> id: String
> player_name: String
> PTS: Int
>   }
> 
> type Query {
> players(id: String): [Player]
>   }
```

`This is the relevant query`

```
> export const GET_PLAYER = gql`
> query Players($playersId: String) {
> players(id: $playersId) {
> _id
> game_id
> player_name
> PTS
>        }
>      }
```

When using this query in apollo sandbox with a relevant id I get this array of data

```
> {
>   "data": {
>     "players": [
>       {
>         "_id": "63ea73d4297006c9dffa349a",
>         "game_id": 401468894,
>         "id": "4432158",
>         "PTS": 23
>       },
>         {
>         "_id": "63ea73d3297006c9dffa3463",
>         "game_id": 401468888,
>         "id": "4432158",
>         "PTS": 21
>       },
>       {
>         "_id": "63ea73d1297006c9dffa3387",
>         "game_id": 401468870,
>         "id": "4432158",
>         "PTS": 12
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> }
>
```

THIS IS THE DATA I WANT^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

But when calling on this query in the front end with useQuery like so

`const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_PLAYER, {     variables: { playersId:player},   });`

It gives me an array of 3(my limit amount) of only the first object like so

```
> 0
> 
> {__typename: 'Player', _id: '63ea73d3297006c9dffa3463', game_id: 401468888, id: '4432158', player_name: 'evan-mobley', …}
> 1
> 
> {__typename: 'Player', _id: '63ea73d3297006c9dffa3463', game_id: 401468888, id: '4432158', player_name: 'evan-mobley', …}
> 2
> 
> {__typename: 'Player', _id: '63ea73d3297006c9dffa3463', game_id: 401468888, id: '4432158', player_name: 'evan-mobley', …}
>
```

As you can see they are all the same

When I take the variable out of the resolver like so

```
> players: async (parent, { id }) => {
> return Player.find().sort({ game_id: -1 }).limit(3);
>     },
```

It fetches data how I would expect it to, but if I put any variable in that find operator, I get a list of 3 duplicates.

Other resolvers on same page, with very similar functionality, but using a different collection work perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

So I found the issue, it was because I had multiple properties id in my object that weren't unique identifiers. Apollo cached these as the same because multiple datapoints had the same "id"